# How can synchronous event demultiplexing be a solution to busy waiting?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom-events

I am trying to understand the how can synchronous event demultiplexing be a solution to busy waiting.

Suppose  there are 3 IO operations and we have a code which is constantly looping to check if any of the 3 operation has data available to read.

```
    arry = [event1 , event2 , event3]

    while(arry is not empty)
    {

        for(i = 0 ; i <= 2 ; i++)
        {
            if(arry[i] has something to read)
            {
                read data;
            }
            else
            {
               continue to next i;
            }

            if(arry[i] read has finished){ 
                remove i from arry
             }
        }
    }
```

Above pseudo code does a busy waiting.

Now in synchronous event demultiplexing or to say reactor pattern an event listener is there to respond to an event as it occurs. But how can an event listener do that without busy waiting ?

Comment: I have to admit I've never heard of "*synchronous event demultiplexing*". Can you point to some resources describing it, or maybe put some example (pseudo) code in your question?

Comment: You don't do anything synchronous with JavaScript events. But that doesn't mean the reactor pattern can't work asynchronously as well - instead of busy-waiting between the events arrive, you just schedule your looping code on every of the awaited events.

Answer (score 9):

A process is an instance (executing a task or a module) of a computer program that has been executed. Within a single process we can have multiple components called threads. You can visualize a thread  like a to-do-list that has some number of instructions that need to be executed by the CPU of your computer. Think thread as a worker.

Imagine you have a 10 floor apartment. And you have a single worker with instructions and it has to knock each door to gather data from. In busy waiting , this poor worker, starting from first floor, will knock each door to check if data is ready to receive or not. It will do this up to the top floor. Then it will do the same process in his way down. This time it will skip the doors that it already received data before. So it will keep running up and down till it receives data from each door. This is basically what busy waiting is.

As you can see, with single thread, we can handle different resources without blocking. However this is not efficient, it will make the CPU consume a lot of memory and causes context switches which is extra hard work for the CPU. Also, a thread will waste most of its time for waiting, while it is waiting, the CPU will still be working.

Why is event demultiplexing a solution or more efficient?

Instead of all this heavy work, our single thread will not run up and down. It is not a worker anymore, it is a manager now and receives extra support by libuv library which uses the power of C++. Libuv will collect all the data with event demultiplexer, demultiplexer will include what data came from which door and what to do with this data, then it will pass the necessary data to event queue then event queue will pass the control to event loop. Now event loop's job is just  to check if there is a waiting event, if there is, it will push it to the call stack which is where functions get executed.

event demultiplexer is called synchronous because, it does not knock 2 doors at the same time.

It is really hard to explain this complex subject in a simple way. I hope it helps.

Comment: What makes demultiplexer more efficient in collecting information about which data came from which door. How is it different from simple busy waiting? e.g. in busy-waiting, you'd go door to door from first floor to 10th. 
Can you explain how same works efficiently with demultiplexer in place?

Answer (score 0):

That's not the way it works in JS.

When you make some request likely to trigger an asynchronous notification, you have to provide a callback that will be called with the request result as a parameter.

Your pseudo-code would rather look like:

```
// request completion callback
function handle_request_notification (request status and associated data)
{
    store request data wherever you like
    if all requests are complete (without error), do what you want to do
    (now that you have a complete set of data)
}

// issuing requests
do_request (whatever1, handle_request_notification)
do_request (whatever2, handle_request_notification)
do_request (whatever3, handle_request_notification)
```

So basically it's the library that handles the asynchronous requests that will activate the bit of code needed when there is actually something to read (or the request failed).

Each specific library will have its own way of doing this.

You can have a look at Ajax for a start, that's probably the mother of all JS asynchronous libraries.

Or if you want something simpler to study the basics, just use a timer :)

Answer (score 0):

Busy waiting wastes cpu time checking for resources that aren't available most of the time. On the other hand the event demultiplexer iterates over events, so it only iterates when there's data ready to be processed.

Answer (score 0):

In your code above, the for loop will iterate over and over again, which will waste CPU resource.

On the other hand, reactor pattern code would look like this:

```
array = [event1 , event2 , event3];
while(events = demultiplexer.watch(array)) {
   events.forEach(event => {
       \\ Data must be available at this point
       process(event.data);
       array.remove(event);
   })
}
```

This call `events = demultiplexer.watch(array)` is synchronous, so it will block the thread until any of the resources are available. When one of the resource is available, the demultiplexer will return it, only then would the for loop be executed.

So in short, busy waiting will waste CPU time for iterating over resources which are not available most of the time, while with reactor pattern, it would only iterate over available resources.